# Is postgres_fdw reliable to do daily refresh of 5 million rows?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I'm using postgres_fdw to refresh my application database on daily bases.
So, is this the best process to follow?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I don't have any problem with FDW, but my question is simple that the practice to use FDW to transfer the records between two different database on daily bases is correct or not.